# Color combination for 3d mesh segmentation

Tags: color, interface-design

I'm a programmer, with really bad aesthetic feeling. Please sorry if I use not specific terminology, I'm not a graphic designer.

I'd like to automatically generate a variable size cool combination that can be neat. I know that there are some rules to do it but I have specific contains.

For instance I have a triangular 3D mesh where the triangles are segmented in various groups. I'd like to find a colour combination with those constrains:
- one tonality / colour (let's say blue)
- no perky colours (not pure blue, not pure cyan)
- the colour has to be distinguishable one from the other

The thing I have to achieve is like this:

[image]

But this image does not fit the first two constrains.

Do you have some advice?

Comment: So, you want each group with a different color? You want warm or cool colors? What are the variables?

Comment: blue is a cool color, isn't it?